# Asking for arguments, Could someone please point out what I've done wrong. It keeps coming up with fname not defined

Tags: python-2.7

```
def fbi_badge_name(fname, lname):
    print fname, lname + ' is a special agent '
    fname = raw_input(' what is your first name: ')
    lname = raw_input(' what is your second name: ')
print fbi_badge_name (fname, lname)
```

Comment: Read the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).

Comment: How can you output before you've inputted?

Comment: I've reformatted your code and provided an answer based on this. Indentation is *critical* in python. Please be aware that unless you verify (or change) the code indentation, this is only a guess. In addition, the precise error message would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the formatting of your code is correct, you are asking for input *after* already trying to use it. Be aware that python defines scope by indentation. Thus, your calls to raw_input only assign to names local to the function.

Let's examine how your code is evaluated:

```
# stack 1
def fbi_badge_name(fname, lname):  # define function fbi_badge_name
    # ...
    # any code here is not executed yet
print fbi_badge_name (fname, lname)  # call previously defined function

# stack 2
# execute fbi_badge_name, with fname=<stack1 fname>, lname=<stack1 lname>
print fname, lname + ' is a special agent '  # print local fname, local lname, local string
fname = raw_input(' what is your first name: ')  # redefine local fname
lname = raw_input(' what is your second name: ')  # redefine local lname
```

So, you have two problems here:

- First, you are trying to use fname and lname before they are ever defined. This actually happens in your *last* line, where you call print. The reason is that the previous code of the function has not been executed yet. It has only been defined.
- Second, you *never* set fname or lname in the *scope* of the last print. Since you set both only in the function, they are only available in the function's scope. Using the same name in multiple scopes will not make the objects pass over.

Your code should probably look like this:

```
def fbi_badge_name(fname, lname):
    print fname, lname + ' is a special agent '
# note that the code resume at the initial indentation
fname = raw_input(' what is your first name: ')
lname = raw_input(' what is your second name: ')
print fbi_badge_name (fname, lname)
```